# Binding TabItem Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to have my TabItem Collapsed or Hidden. I've tried many solutions and none have worked. The Tab Item still remains

If I may get some guidance please.

one solution I've Tried

```
<TabItem >
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Visibility="Collapsed">
           <TextBlock Text="Transactions" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <panes:Transactions />
</TabItem>

private Visibility statementVisibility;  
public Visibility StatementVisibility { get { return statementVisibility; } set { statementVisibility = value; OnPropertyChanged("StatementVisibillity"); } }
```

Changed "Collapsed" to StatementVisibility and still nothing.

UPDATE:
After poking around, I've found a link to the TabItems that I think may play a factor.

Generic.xaml

```
<ListBox Foreground="#FFF" Name="TabSelector" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=Tabs}">
     <ListBox.Background>
           <SolidColorBrush Color="#333"/>
     </ListBox.Background>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" BorderBrush="#22000000">
                   <TextBlock FontSize="14" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Padding="6" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
              </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>


<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Background="White" BorderThickness="0">
    <ContentPresenter Name="PART_TabbedFormPresenter" 
                            Content="{Binding TabbedForm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type shell:ActionScreenControl}}}" 
                            DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type shell:ActionScreenControl}}}">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>
</Border>
```

Loanview.xaml.cs

```
<shell:ActionScreenControl.TabbedForm>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem......./>
        <TabItem......./>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <TextBlock Text="Transactions" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <panes:Transactions />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</shell:ActionScreenControl.TabbedForm>
```

Comment: Create another tab with nothing but a simple TextBlock and test.

Comment: Hi @Blam it shows "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock"

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong it works from me.  Post a simple but complete example to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Blam Updated code btw if you didn't notice, thanks for trying though. I Got it to collapse. Had to set DataTrigger for the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Visibility` property on the actual `TabItem` itself:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Transactions" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <panes:Transactions />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Ahhhh... you want to data bind. Then you'll need to use a [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) element and a `bool` property:

```
<TabItem Visibility="{Binding YourBoolProperty, 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Text="Transactions" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <panes:Transactions />
</TabItem>
```

See the [`IValueConverter` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to see how to use a converter.

Comment: Tried that and still appearing but instead it says System.Windows.Controls.Stackpanel

Comment: Try using it in a new project... yours sounds messed up. In a new project, you won't see this `TabItem`... of course you need to put it into a `TabControl` first.

Comment: I've tried Boolean to Visibility Converter also. I just set Collapsed to see if it'll actually collapse before setting bindings.

Comment: Hi Sheridan, your comment made me very curious if there was more to my tabItem and it looks like it's encapsulated within some other stuff.

Comment: I think edits have to be made to the contentpresenter but Unsure how to do that for the visilibities.

Answer (score 0):

This is from production code and it works

```
<TabItem  Visibility="{Binding Path=MyGabeLib.CurUser.DisplayTSQL, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}">
        <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}">TSQL</TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyGabeLib.Search.CurrentTSQL, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Courier New"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</TabItem>
```

If you are returning Visibility then you would not need a converter
Try with a simple TextBlock - I suspect you have a datacontext problem